# Сообщения низкого количества

Tags: предложение, очередь-проверок

В [очереди проверок сообщений низкого качества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts) порой попадаются сообщения, которые, возможно, устраняют ошибку из поставленного вопроса, например в подобном виде:

> Используйте `double` вместо `int`.

при этом совершенно не объясняя причину. Такое сообщение удалять (нажимать кнопку <kbd>Рекомендовать удаление</kbd>) всё же не стоит, но хорошо бы донести до его автора соответствующую информацию, о том, что надо бы ответ дополнить.

В некоторых случаях под такими сообщениями можно увидеть [комментарий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/587754/js-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-css-%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85/587813#comment788755_587813) вида:

> Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник.

Возможно, эта опция доступна только модераторам (или вовсе вводится вручную), но хотелось бы добавить нечто подобное и в сам механизм проверки сообщений низкого качества. Например, к имеющимся кнопкам:

[image: кнопочки]

добавить ещё одну, типа <kbd>Рекомендовать дополнение</kbd>, после которой будет автоматически добавляться упомянутый комментарий (или после ещё одного окна с выбором более специфического сообщения) и эта проверка будет засчитываться должным образом в стаж проверяющего.

Comment: В заголовке _количества_ - это опечатка?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov это фишечка.

Answer (score 3):

На StackOverflow этот механизм уже есть, и известен как **[триаж](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278380/2076787)**. **Правда, действует он только для вопросов.** Это эдакая первичная сортировка вопросов. Основана на том же принципе, что и [медицинская сортировка (триаж, отсюда и название)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) пострадавших на тех, кому помощь нужна прямо сейчас, кому нужна не прямо сейчас, и кому уже не понадобится.

Это отдельная очередь, в которой голосуют, **можно ли починить вопрос** (исходя из уже имеющейся информации, без вмешательства автора вопроса) **или он** настолько **безнадёжен**, что надо рассматривать закрытие и удаление.

Вопросы, которые **можно** починить, направляются в очередь "Помощь и улучшение" (Help & Improvement) и там редактируются.

Механизм **экспериментальный** и Shog9 год назад [предостерегал другие сообщества от "добровольного согласия на этот эксперимент"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251744/318749). Возможно, сейчас ситуация изменилась, но у меня нет об этом информации.

---

А сейчас таким ответам можно ставить **минус** и **оставлять комментарий**, но если технически ответ имеется, то он <kbd>Выглядит нормально</kbd>, даже если он плохой. Уведомление будет от комментария. А если ещё заметить, что снимете минус как только проблема будет устранена, ещё и мотивации добавите.

Comment: Это не совсем то, т.к. "Triage" существует параллельно с "Low Quality Posts". Моё предложение именно по доработке в проверке "Сообщений низкого качества". С обязательным уведомлением автора такого сообщения.

Comment: @alexolut оставил дополнение по поводу текущей ситуации.

Comment: Палец не поднимается кликать в таких случаях "Выглядит нормально".

Comment: @alexolut да, я [жаловался в чате на это](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=32106352#32106352). Но так уж задумана очередь.

Comment: Ну вот, а я пожаловался на Мете :) Посмотрим, как быстро появится метка [meta-tag:статус-так-задумано].

Comment: Шикарная картинка в чате, кстати.