# Причина "Сообщение содержит лишь текст задачи" применяется не так, как задумывалась изначально

Tags: обсуждение, причины-закрытия

В стандартных причинах закрытия есть причина со следующей формулировкой:

> Сообщение содержит лишь текст задачи, в котором нет описания проблемы, либо вопрос чисто формален («как мне выполнить это задание»

Эта причина закрытия была введена для того, чтобы отсечь волну копипасты задач из учебников, обычно накрывающей сайт во время сессии. Ее ввели как средство борьбы с ленивыми студентами, задачи от которых раздражали активных участников сообщества.

Изначально задумывалось, что причина будет применяться к вопросам, которые:

- заданы в императивном стиле ("Вот задача, решите!")
- не показывают ни малейшей попытки решить задачу самостоятельно (копипаст из учебника)
- прямо показывают, что топикастер - халявщик, не собирающийся учиться, желающий просто "сдать лабу".

Краткая история введения (выделение болдом - мое):

1. [Работа за автора](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/231/). Топовый ответ (+36 / -3)

   > «похожая причина закрытия уже существовала, но **ею часто злоупотребляли**. „Как сделать X, используя Y?“ вопросы полезны, даже если они не содержат код».
2. [Допустимы ли вопросы, где подразумевается работа за автора?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4882/) Позиция администрации (+12 / -1):

   > Допустимы и приветствуются.
   >   (Вопросы, в которых подразумевается работа за автора != вопросы–домашние задания.)
3. [Вопросы–домашние задания](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5043/). Позиция администрации (+12 / -1):

   > Пожалуйста, помните, что вопрос делает плохим не то, что он является домашним заданием, а то, что он **не содержит конкретной прикладной проблемы** в формулировке или **надуман и не имеет никакой практической пользы**
4. [Что делать с домашней работой и ленью?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4992/). (+26 / -5) - собственно, введение стандартной причины в текущем ее виде.
5. [Вы сломали мой StackOverflow, часть 3: “текст задачи” — это не отсутствие кода!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5953/) - (+17 / -4) - попытка Qwertiy указать на наблюдаемые негативные последствия.

Негативные последствия действительно наблюдаются, причем именно в том виде, в котором они наблюдались при попытке ввести точно такую же причину закрытия на enSO.

Предложившие причину закрытия подразумевали, что закрывающий как-то (по косвенным нетехническим признакам) определит, что автор вопроса проявил лень и просто скопипастил задачу. Реальные проверяющие же при этом воспринимают сам текст причины закрытия как часть правил и не пытаются следовать ее духу:

1. Голосуют за закрытие только потому, что в вопросе нет кода, но есть текстовый вопрос. Т.е. закрывают [вообще любые вопросы без кода и другим советуют так делать](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6126/177221).
2. Расширяют понятие "лени" на "слишком простой вопрос! похоже, топикастеру лень заглянуть в учебник/документацию", и закрывают с этой причиной базовые вопросы по технологиям ([которые у нас полностью онтопичны, и вообще всячески приветствуются](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4581/177221), +27 / -1)

**Причиной закрытия часто злоупотребляют**:

- Ее используют на простых вопросах по основам технологий.
- Ее используют вместо других, более подходящих причин, только потому, что в вопросе нет кода, лишая тем самым автора подсказки, как ему исправить вопрос.
- Ее используют только потому, что автор упомянул, что он студент, пусть даже он и пытался решить задачу самостоятельно.

Стандартная причина закрытия воспринимается как жесткое правило, которое не требует от закрывающего учитывать какие-то хитрые оговорки на Мете. Более того, причина закрытия и должна быть жесткой частью правил - она должна явно показать автору вопроса, что он сделал не так. Без дополнительных заходов на Мету и чтения длинной переписки.

---

Ок, стоит посмотреть, какие же вопросы действительно закрывают с этой причиной. [Вот запрос на SEDE. Вопросы, на которых висели предложения закрыть вопрос как домашку, на момент снэпшота](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/edit/744728#resultSets). Открываем его и идем по все вопросам подряд (порядок может отличаться):

- [Как реализовать серверный часть приложение в моем случае?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/725369/) - автор явно проявил старания, вопрос стоило закрыть как "слишком общий".
- [Отсортировать значения c определенным количеством](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/725914/) - домашка, но закрыта после того, как на вопрос дан заплюсованный ответ.
- [Как сделать GUI таймер в Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/726594) - закрыт на момент написанияпоста. просто работа за автора. никаких признаков домашки.
- [Помогите пожалуйста сделать такой эффект scroll как в примере](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/729811/) - даже близко не домашка. закрыт, 4 голоса дано после того, как автор привел код.
- [Найти количество элементов, меньших каждого конкретного](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/726994/) - учебное задание. в комментах автор явно проявляет знание темы, а не просто ждет ответа. мы наказываем за сам факт обращения автора на SO. с переносом комментов в тело - imho, онтопик.
- [Выборка с таблицы, созданные массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/730681/) - прикладной вопрос. на момент снепшота в SEDE на нем было два голоса за закрытие.
- [Assembler - Как создать файл?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/730676/) - вопрос по основам технологии. закрыт.
- [Пример простого класса в C++ (например сложение/вычитание матриц)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/730533/) - поиск примера / учебных материалов. но закрыт как "домашка"
- [Отправка header методом POST PHP (замена xhr.setRequestHeader)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/729695/) - вопрос по основе технологии. не могу понять, почему это закрыли как домашку
- [Как создать форму в WordPress которая будет заполнять кастомный тип записи](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/729605/) - два голоса за "домашку" на вопросе про wordpress!
- [Как удалить из строки 1+ подряд идущих звездочек](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/730262/) - онтопичный вопрос с прикладной проблемой. на нем два голоса с причиной "домашка".

Можно перебрать весь список - но картина, на мой взгляд, ясна. В текущей формулировке эту причину закрытия применяют ко всему подряд, включая обычные онтопичные вопросы. Да, она полезна для отфильтровывания некоторого количества редких домашних заданий. Но сейчас вместе с водой мы выплескиваем ребенка.

С указанием этой причины было закрыто 130 вопросов за последний месяц. Судя по всему, большинство из них не являлись домашними заданиями.

---

**Формулировку причины стоит изменить, чтобы избежать злоупотреблений. Если придумать однозначную формулировку невозможно - причину стоит удалить из стандартных ради прекращения злоупотреблений.**

Я оставлю два ответа по умолчанию. Если можете предложить новую формулировку причины - предлагайте, а не просто минусуйте варианты.

Пожалуйста, оценивайте свои варианты с точки зрения решения как оригинальной проблемы (борьбы с ленью), так и текущей (злоупотребления из-за слишком общей формулировки).

UP: я не люблю халявщиков. Мое *личное* мнение - домашней работе без попыток решения - не место на сайте. Но борьба с ней не должна наносить ущерб добросовестным посетителям.

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5953/178988

Comment: Эта тема выросла по следам обсуждений в чате. Думаю, что стоит упомянуть ссылки на обсуждение -- там много полезных размышлений по теме данного топика и смежных. [Начало тут](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40635255#40635255), продолжение [тут](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40675970#40675970).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос**. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности** при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Не будем ходить вокруг да около и быть вежливыми с халявщиками. Давайте прямо скажем им - покажи сорс или уходи :)

<sub>UP: Заменил "Домашние задания" на "Учебные задания" для более точного охвата проблемных вопросов</sub>

Comment: А как бороться с «трудность вызвало вообще всё задание от начала до конца, вот вам код hello world с первой лекции»?

Comment: @VladD никак. отвечать "сорри, надо было ходить на лекции"

Comment: @VladD практика показывает, что к этому моменту вопрос наберет дикое количество минусов, посереет и умрет через неделю.

Comment: Окей, я не против.

Comment: Вопросы, вроде бы не сереют. Но пропадают из главной при достижении минус 8.

Comment: А если на "приведите код", он вываливает портянку не пойми чего? Поменять причину закрытия просто так нельзя, хотя надо бы уже указывать, что вопрос не содержит MCVE.

Comment: @alexolut вы думаете нужна возможно менять причину закрытия? Чтобы без переоткрытия сразу поменять не отзываясь голоса.

Comment: Подскажите, как вы (или кто–либо другой) определит, что вопрос — домашка? Мир, все–таки, не всегда прямолинеен.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky это предложение об изменении текста **существующей причины**, которую [ввели ради борьбы с домашней работой](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4992). Вопрос "как определить, что вопрос - домашка" стоило задать *до ввода текущей причины*. Судя по куче онтопика, который попал под текущую формулировку причины, выяснить это так и не смогли. Если вы считаете, что *у проверяющего* нет способа однозначно определить, является ли вопрос домашней работой - стоит перестать использовать механизм закрытия для борьбы с домашкой. И просто удалить причину из списка.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: Ну, во многих вопросах это говорится вообще прямо. Последний пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/733708/10105

Comment: Ну и домашки _видно_. Если в вопросе написано «вывод результата производить в текстовый файл output.txt», это очевидная домашка. Или конкурсное задание, которое не сильно отличается.

Comment: Формулировка "домашнее задание" исключает из рассмотрения конкурсные задачки и прочие смежные источники заданий. Юзеры будут отвечать: "Но это *не домашнее* задание!" Мотивировочно-направляющая часть корректна, а исходный посыл мутный.

Comment: @Squidward проблема в том, что те, кто хочет именно закрывать (а не просто минусовать) домашки, конкурсы, и прочее, не понимают сути механизма закрытия (требования правки). Поэтому нельзя сформулировать причину, которая борола бы лень в общем слуае, но не была применима к почти всему онтопику. Т.к. никто не может описать, что же это такое - проявление лени. Но требуют оставить причину закрытия "лень". Типа "ну, лень, все ж могут ее распознать!"

Comment: @PashaPash В предлагаемом варианте есть "укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности", в результате не получится просто взять и закрыть вопрос, если в нём есть корректный разбор и попытки решения задачки. То есть, если кто-то вздумает злоупотреблять причиной закрытия, то можно без стеснения давать по шапке. Текущая же формулировка причины слишком мутная, поэтому, как мне кажется, и возникают проблемы с интерпретацией.

Comment: @Squidward для конкурса нужна метка [tag:соревнование] как минимум, ну и если обязать в соревнованиях давать ответ от ТС, то уже точно не закроют как домашку.

Comment: @alexolut Речь про олимпиадные задачки, а не гольф.

Comment: @PashaPash Здесь в комментариях прозвучало словосочетание "учебное задание". По-моему, оно лучше подходит, чем текущее "домашнее".

Comment: Добавил данную причину.  Уверен, что это _не правильное решение_. Для нас плохой вопрос — это вопрос, который не может возникнуть на практике, а не домашнее задание как таковое (хотя многие из них действительно «надуманные»). Нам обязательно придется вернутся к данному вопросу. В текущем виде – это не решение, это «костыль».

Comment: Теперь я буду знать кто это придумал! Мне очень нравится!

Answer (score 4):

Проблемы "неправильного" использования этой причины заключаются не в том, что причина плоха, а в том, что **для решения проблемы лени используется неправильный механизм**.

На сайте есть два независимых механизма оценики вопроса:

- Голосование (плюсы и минусы). Служит для субъективной оценки чего угодно - хоть сути вопроса, хоть автора и его намеряний.
- "Требование правки". Оно же закрытие. Служит для того, чтобы превратить вопрос, на который ответ ответ дать нельзя, в хороший онтопичный вопрос.

**Да, ленивые вопросы заслуживают активного минусования.** У минусов есть огромные преимущества:

- Они доступны гораздо более широкому кругу участников
- Они бесплатны и действуют немедленно
- Ленивого участника *автоматически банит* при достаточно большом количестве минусов
- Заминусованные вопросы уходят с главной, что снижает шанс ответа на них почти до нуля
- Рейтинг всего в -3 позволяет участникам с высокой репутацией просто **взять и удалить вопрос** в три клика.

**Если лично вам вам не нравятся вопросы-домашки - минусуйте их. Если вопрос набрал достаточно минусов - удаляйте**.

На сайте достаточно участников с репутацией, дающей право на прямое удаление вопросов.

**Требовать правки от автора домашки - бесполезно**. Очевидно, что домашнее задание от ленивого студента (мы же именно с этим явлением боремся?), как его не равь, не перестанет быть заданием от ленивого студента!

- Закрытие вовлекает в ревью минимум 5 человек. Это огромная **трата времени постоянных участников** ради какого-то "ленивого студента".
- Голос за закрытие потенциально привлекает к вопросу внимание, что *повышает шанс ответа*.
- Окончательное закрытие вопроса обычно задерживается, и к моменту закрытия на домашку успевают ответить.
- Голос за закрытие на домашке забивает очередь закрытия. Соответственно, остальные вопросы, в которых автору действительно стоило бы подтолкнуть к правке, провисят в очереди дольше.
- Голос за закрытие потенциально спасает вопрос от минусов - ведь в интерфейсе просмотра очереди не отображаются элементы для голосования

Единственное преимущество закрытия как механизма - то, что на сайте есть стандартный интерфейс для просмотра списка вопросов, попавших под закрытие. Во всем остальном этот механизим *гораздо хуже* банального "заминусовать и удалить".

Если причину закрытия и стоит оставить - то в виде исключения, чтобы позволить участникам с репутацией < 10K тоже противодействовать *ненавистной лично им*
 (пусть даже и через не совсем подходящий механизм).

"Борцам с ленью" стоит пересмотреть доступные им инструменты. Текущее количество активных участников с репутацией > 10k позволяет удалять домашку практически сразу. Если сообщество декларирует ненависть к домашним заданиям, но они живут больше суток - значит стоит искать пути для более эффективного использования доступных инструментов.

Comment: Я понимаю, что в данном ответе вы всячески будете пиарить минуса, но [кажется](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40678589#40678589), есть более подходящий механизм -- триаж (ссылки: [раз](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4055/213987), [два](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278380/5752652), [три](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295650/5752652))

Comment: @AK да, есть. одновременно с пиаром минусов я буду выяснять, как его включить :)

Comment: Наше сообщество часто упоминают, как одно из самых крупных по числу задаваемых вопросов в день (200 вопросов/сутки). Вероятно, даже если есть опасения у Shog9 о том, что это опасный инструмент -- у нас найдутся аргументы, почему он нужен именно нам: у нас много вопросов и большая часть из них нуждается в улучшении.

Comment: @PashaPash, вряд ли триаж как-то особо поможет с домашкой (после закрытия, судьба предрешена), но интересная вещь.

Comment: @Other триаж уменьшит шанс получения домашкой ответа. Ведь это основная цель всей борьбы?

Comment: @PashaPash, я просто не уверен что это действительно поможет.

Answer (score -2):

Да, исходный текст сообщения о закрытии не вполне хорош, и как показывают примеры в вопросе, нуждается в улучшении.

Предлагаю следующий текст.

> Сообщение содержит лишь текст задачи, в котором нет описания реальной проблемы, интересной сообществу программистов. Проблема, поставленная в вопросе, искусственна, имеет смысл лишь в качестве учебного задания, и не является упрощением реальной проблемы, возникающей при программировании.

Плюсы: лучше первоначального текста.

Минусы: текст слишком длинный, и возможно всё ещё не вполне точно отражает суть проблемы.

---

И да, нужно сделать явное исключение для гольфа. Потому что гольф — тоже проблема, не пришедшая из реальности. Но не в этом тексте (он и так слишком длинный).

Comment: Отсекли одни злоупотребления - добавили другие. С такой причиной будут любые учебные задания закрывать.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Ну, я пытался избежать этого, используя «не является упрощением реальной проблемы, возникающей при программировании».

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Мне кажется, лучше будет написать разъясняющий правило пост на Мете, и дать в причине закрытия ссылку на него. Например, в качестве варианта подойдёт [это](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5043/10105).

Comment: стоит убрать " Сам вопрос отсутствует или чисто формален («как мне выполнить это задание»)." - именно это сейчас подталкивает к закрытию

Comment: @PashaPash: Согласен, да.

Comment: @PashaPash вот нет, "сам вопрос отсутствует" - это основная часть. Вот часть "или чисто формален"  можно и порезать.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Может быть, попробуйте сформулировать, чтобы не убирать «вопрос отсутствует»?

Answer (score -2):

*(В процессе разработки, требуется обратная связь)*

Хотим упирать на надуманность/учебность/непрактичность проблемы — так давайте прямо так и напишем, развернув мысль:

> **Вопрос не о конкретной прикладной проблеме.** Ответы на этот вопрос ни для кого другого (кроме автора вопроса) не принесут непосредственной практической пользы в решении проблем, связанных с программированием. Публикация здесь ответов на подобные вопросы бессмысленна для общественности, а в случае надуманных учебных заданий даже вредна.

Заметки к размышлению об этой формулировке:

- Не делает прямого предположения об учебно-надуманности конкретно этого вопроса, но прямо объявляет ответы на этот сорт вопросов вредными для общественности — если практическая польза от решения заключается максимум в возможности сдать его преподавателю, к примеру. Этот тезис я не смог поместить в формулировку в достаточной мере сжато.
- Упирает на важный аспект SO, полезность ответов для других. Многие вопросы из разряда "работа за автора" под этот критерий не попадают, но не потому что требуют работы за автора, а потому что являются одноразовыми и бесполезны для других.
- Можно поставить под сомнение, насколько достоверно случайные люди могут определить бесполезность вопроса для широкого круга лиц. Но на то механизм закрытия и требует пять голосов, а не один.
- Не даёт советов о том, что можно сделать, чтобы спасти вопрос. Но большая часть таких вопросов, по моим наблюдениям, безнадёжны. Эта черта не делает эту причину закрытия чем-то хуже других — опечатка/невоспроизводимость тоже безнадёжна.
- Её "приговорный характер" (отсутствие рекомендаций к спасению вопроса), среди прочего, заставит задуматься, прежде чем её ставить — нет ли более подходящих причин. Скажем, "слишком общий".

Comment: Это вызовет закрытие тех учебных заданий, авторы которых пытались решить задачу самостоятельно, не смогли, и пришли на SO. Кроме того, базовые вопросы по основам технологии тоже не являются основами о конкретных прикладных проблемах. Т.е. под эту формулировку попадают многие из существующих топовых вопросов на сайте.

Comment: Если бы мне таким закрыли вопрос -- я бы долго думал, что мне хотели сказать. Предпочитаю простую, чёткую, понятную, правдивую формулировку "халявщикам тут не место".

Comment: @PashaPash Сама по себе попытка решения не делает вопрос недостойным закрытия. Встречали вопросы, где ТС поместил код, не имеющий к изложенной задаче никакого отношения под видом попытки решения? А вот сужение задачи до более конкретного места, с которым возникло непонимание -- делает. Как под эту формулировку попадают простые вопросы, не вижу, нужны примеры.

Comment: @D-side мы же лень собрались наказывать? пусть покажет конкретный сорс, имеющий отношение к решению!

Comment: @PashaPash если из этого сорса становится понятно, какие аспекты ТС уже разобрал, а в чём застрял -- пожалуйста. И что?

Comment: @D-side причина закрытия должна прямо доносить до топикастера, что он должен сделать. т.е. формулировка должна объяснить ему "сделал X - и вопрос откроем". А ваш вариант - не доносит. Он просто говорит "иди отсюда" :(

Comment: @PashaPash последний пункт, да :|

Comment: ...теперь распавшийся на два.

Comment: Историческая справка: на большом СО кроме нынешних "off-topic", "too broad", "opinion-based", "unclear" была ещё причина "too narrow" (или "too specific", не помню точно), то есть как раз ваша формулировка: слишком узкая задача, которая неинтересна остальным. Эта причина была удалена, потому что вела к злоупотреблениям: слишком много вопросов можно объявить "узкими и специфическими". / Ну и формулировка про вред и прочее слишком груба. Стандартные описания надо поаккуратнее формулировать.

Comment: @Squidward "too localized". Видел. И считаю, что она лучше, чем "это задание" или "на домашки смотрим только видя попытки решения", потому что последние две о полезности/качестве вопроса не говорят решительно ничего. В самих по себе заданиях и домашках проблемы нет, у них часто встречаются некие общие черты, которые нас не устраивают. Копать надо к ним.

Comment: Формулировка задумана жёсткой. Но это может действительно быть не лучшей идеей, т. к. один подумает прежде чем "выписывать приговор", а другой слепо последует за ним, и реально уровень осторожности выше не станет.

Answer (score -4):

Эту причину закрытия нельзя сформулировать однозначно. [Опыт enSO однозначно показывает](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/231/), что в любой формулировке этой причиной будут злоупотреблять. Мы уже прошли половину пути enSO к отказу от этой причины в списке стандартных.

Причину в текущем виде стоит удалить. Вопросы стоит основываясь полностью на технической сути вопроса, на его реальном качестве, а не на наших предположениях о намеряниях автора, и тем более не на принципе "новичкам тут не место, читайте документацию и идите в гугл".

Comment: Данный ответ мне не нравится больше всего. В сообществе есть консенсус по поводу домашки: ей не место на сайте. Вопрос в том, как "не выплеснуть с водой и ребёночка": чтобы и домашку можно было закрыть и нормальные вопросы не закрывались. Подумаю, как можно выкрутиться из этого противоречия, возможно напишу отдельный ответ.

Comment: @AK там в вопросе написано - если минусуете вариант "убрать причину" - пожалуйста, формулируйте альтернативы. до минусования :)

Comment: С учётом того, что появились альтернативы (не мои, но хорошие) и я туда кинул upvote  -- считаю, что имею моральное право вернуть минуса на плохие варианты. ;)

Comment: @AK есть консенсус "домашке не место на сайте" и есть дико деструктивное решение "давайте бороться с домашкой с помощью механизма закрытия". Ребеночков оказалось гораздо больше, чем воды, и их выплескивают уже пол года.

Answer (score -8):

Текущая формулировка причины вполне хороша, проблем с ней нет.

То, что при этом значительное количество вопросов закрывается с абсолютно неприменимой причиной, и регулярно закрываются / удаляются вопросы от новичков - это нормально. Да, много новичков после этого не вернутся на ruSO - ок, нам не нужны неудачники!

В крайнем случае - попытаемся решить это административными мерами.

Модераторам вменить в обязанности присматривать за соблюдением задуманных принципов употребления этой причины (сотни в месяц). Проверять каждый случай на правильность. Выписывать предупреждения тем, кто использует причину закрытия неправильно (не для борьбы с ленью). Если ревьювер продолжает использовать причину неправильно - принимать меры, вплоть до бана. Нам не нужны обидчивые ревьверы.

Comment: Даёте пункты голосовать - делайте их беспристрастными, у Вас же от пунктов аж разит что **нужно** любому выбрать. Выразите в вопросе свои соображения.

Comment: Данный вариант мне не нравится увеличением нагрузки на корпус модераторов.

Comment: @Other да, придется выбрать. этот пункт - выбор "ничего не менять"

Comment: Вот так и напишите, я Ваши соображения понимаю и даже разделяю в какой-то мере, но вот в таком виде это просто агитка: "Давайте снесём без альтернативы!".

Comment: @Other да, я разделяю ваши соображения. и полностью их понимаю. я за борьбу с ленью. но сейчас эту причину используют для борьбы с вопросами

Comment: Проблема есть, но нельзя убирать решение, работающее **кое-как**, не придумав решения, работающего **хорошо**.

Comment: @Other текущая проблема - по-быстрому, внедрили решение, которое работает кое-как. вместо того, чтобы придумать решение, работающее хорошо. откатить плохое (ужасное!) решение - это хорошее решение?

Comment: Будет **хорошее** решение - я поддержу удаление плохого всем тремя руками, но пока оно единственное, которое хоть как-то работает - удалять его нельзя.

Comment: @Other даже если оно приводит к массовому закрытию онтопичных вопросов?

Comment: Тогда проблема просто сводится к банальному подсчёту: будет ли превалировать количество хороших вопросов, невинно попавших под обстрел, перед теми, кто этого заслуживал? Скорее их рейтинг сравнивать. Если в итоге мы теряем больше, чем разгребаем - надо отключать причину, пусть и без альтернативы (пока). Иначе - потери оправданы, пока ждём фикса пущай живёт.

Comment: @Other ну вот я подсчитал - взял запрос "все сообщения, которые сейчас в очереди с этой причиной". результат подсчета - в вопросе. там 1 из 10 реально является домашкой. и ту закрыли после того, как дали ответ.

Comment: Вы слишком предвзяты. Выполнил запрос, взял 10 первых сообщений, проверил их на свой внутренний детектор и вывод: 3.5 добра (которое, возможно, стоило закрыть по другой причине) и 6.5 того, что я бы тоже закрыл этой причиной.

Comment: @Other это потому, потому что вы проверяете на соответсвие **тексту причины**,  а не на наличие того, ради чего причину ввели. Об этом, собственно, весь вопрос - ввели причину **исключительно ради борьбы с вываливанием на сайт домашки**. не угадали с текстом. текст применим к половине вопросов, включая те, что домашкой не являются. Участники, которые не читают мету, и не знают предыстории, думают, что причину надо применять проверяя вопрос на соответсвие тексту причины. И применяют, точно так же, как вы сделали выше.

Comment: @Other т.е. то, что под причину попало 6.5 - **это и есть проблема**. Потому что текущие правила + консенсу на мете утверждает, что **закрыть следовало только один вопрос из этих 10**. А остальные закрыты из-за того, что **текст причины не соответствует решению и правилам**

Comment: @Other поэтому да, надо выбрать. формально, у нас есть куча участников, прямо нарушающих правила. все эти участники добросовестно использовали текст причины в качестве правил (хотя он таковыми не является). модераторы обязаны из всех забанить? :)

Comment: Мы ушли продолжать сюда: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40665683#40665683