# Проблема "Вопрос содержит лишь текст задачи"

Tags: обсуждение

Какой тревогой сейчас отмечать вопросы, в которых содержится только текст задачи?

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6193/177221

Comment: @PashaPash получается ставить тревогу, что вопрос не может быть улучшен с помощью правок? Или просто ставить минус (без тревоги) в надежде, что вопрос посереет или участник внесет коррективы?

Comment: А лучше не стало...

Comment: @Qwertiy что означает этот комментарий? И в итоге, какое поведение является наиболее актуальным в такой ситуации?

Comment: Наиболее актуальным является причина из принятого ответа, куда @PashaPash дал ссылку. Но вообще-то эта причина не нужна. Если подходит любая другая - надо использовать её. Если нет - просто пройти мимо.