# Что делать с вопросами по типу "нужно решить задачу, но сам я ничего не сделал"?

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов, домашки

Что делать с такими вопросами?

Причина для закрытия:

**Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.**

Сюда вряд ли походит. Да и вопросы зачастую задают вполне конкретные, но они буквально гласят "я не смог сделать, сделайте за меня". На платформе относительно недавно - так и не понял, как же поступать в данной ситуации.

Comment: Почти любой вопрос на платформе - это сделайте за меня :)

Comment: @PashaPash вопрос именно про самые, как бы их назвать, "наглые" вопросы аля "сделайте за меня".

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, у всех свои представления о наглости.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## Ничего не делать

Это вполне могут быть нормальные вопросы

#### Вопросы могут быть атомарные.

Как найти квадратный корень на питоне?

Ну и что надо было сделать перед тем, как задать вопрос? Найти описание вычисления корня сопроцессором, попытаться его реализовать, получить фигню и запостить её в комплект к вопросу? А она тебе там точно нужна?

В такой вопрос придёт куча народу из поисковиков и этот вопрос хороший, закрывать его не требуется. Я, например, гуглил такое, когда пытался что-то на питоне написать.

#### Вопросы могут быть из области, когда просто непонятна общая идея реализации.

Как реализовать поиск ближайших окружностей быстрее чем за квадрат?

Если уже ясно, что идей нет, то зачем тратить время на написание квадратичного кода, который не нужен ни тебе, ни автору? Просто ради галочки "в вопросе есть код"?

#### Вопросы могут в принципе не предполагать наличие кода

[Как обернуть webpack в VS solution?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/961231/178988)

Есть вполне описанные критерии, по которым стандартные проекты не подошли. Что ещё хочется приписать к вопросу?

#### Можно искать чего-то аналогичное существующему в другом языке

Как на Си++ сравнить строки аналогично javascript'овому localeCompare?

Что, надо найти где-то такую реализацию и спросить, как её улучшить? А в ответе скорее всего будет имя одной библиотечной функции?

## Какие вопросы полезны?

- **Вопросы об атомарных действиях, за которыми могут прийти из поисковиков.**
  Нет абсолютно никакого смысла их загромождать неудачными попытками. Одну строчку кода отвечающий и без копипатста написать способен.
- **Вопросы, в которых чётко описана задача и она имеет практическую ценность.**
  Никогда нельзя точно сказать, пытался ли автор что-то сделать или нет, а также, влезли бы вообще его попытки в вопрос и насколько успешно их можно там описать без видео.
- **Вопросы о нетривиальных сложностях.**
  Иногда даже несколько строк кода требуют нескольких дней исследования. Автору может не хватать навыков для решения вопроса, а отвечающий даже при своём высоком уровне может оттуда чему-то научиться. Как и другие люди, заглянувшие в его ответ.

## Какие вопросы бесполезны?

- **Составные вопросы с элементарной задачей без попыток её решить.**
  Именно в эту категорию попадают вопросы-домашки.
- **Слишком комплексные вопросы.**
  Вопросы, очевидно требующие объёмного покрытия нескольких областей одновременно.

Почему же они плохи?

"Как считать 3 числа, выявить максимальное и вывести его?" - это составной вопрос и поэтому он плох. Я никогда не буду гуглить такое. Я могу гуглить как ввести число, как вывести число, как организовать простую эхо-программу. Я могу гуглить как вычислить максимум в массиве или даже из нескольких переменных. Но я не буду гуглить одновременно I/O и математические операции в одном запросе.

"Как написать интернет-магазин с нуля?" - с точки зрения написания кода вопрос абсолютно дохлый. Никто не станет писать интернет-магазин и выкладывать код в ответе с подробными пояснениями, что же он это сделал. Но этот вопрос можно направить в немного иную плоскость, чтобы просить не код, а набор факторов, которые стоит учесть при разработке архитектуры. Тоже где-то на грани, но уже более реалистично. Может ли кто-то такое искать? Ну а мало ли? Да и многие программисты, по крайней мере раньше, хотели попытаться написать свою OC - и тут что-то подобное - можно дать некий чек-лист, служащий подсказкой, но не готовое решение.

Предполагаемый ответ на хороший вопрос должен быть либо довольно кратким (иначе никто просто не станет его писать), либо охватывать какую-то одну область, которую имеет смысл описать полностью (своеобразный faq-вопрос - один раз ответил и дубликатишь).

Answer (score 19):

В борьбе с учебными заданиями наш сайт уверено повторяет путь англоязычного SO с опозданием на несколько лет.

Краткая история:

- Изначально [было решено использовать решение с enSO](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/233/177221). По сути - использовать механизм закрытия по назначению. Оценивать вопросы по содержанию, а не исходя из догадок о намерениях автора. Совсем "наглых" - минусовать (минуса на вопросы бесплатны, сердито, не забивает очередь, трех минусов достаточно)
- Сообществу все-таки захотелось использовать именно механизм закрытия, и была добавлена причина. В причине чуть не угадали с формулировкой, и под нее попали не только "домашки". [Под нее начали закрывать все подряд, от вопросов без кода до "это слишком простой вопрос".](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6189/).
- После полугода массовых чисток невинных вопросов без кода причину переформулировали в текущий вид.

Сейчас ей вроде бы не злоупотребляют. IMO, в текущем виде она больше мешает, чем реально позволяет очистить сайт от "плохих" вопросов. Очередь проверок забита, на интересные "домашки" ответ успевает появиться до закрытия. Неинтересные - и так уходят вниз и удаляются ботом.

Реально никакой пользы сообществу от закрытия вопросов с этой причиной нет. Максимум - моральное удовлетворение закрывающих (Не дал халявщику получить ответ!). Ценой забития очереди на проверку и привлечения еще **4-5 человек на каждую (!!!) домашку**.

Представьте себе эдакий консилиум из 5-ти специалистов, которые советуются "как вы думаете, коллеги, пользователь234342 пытался решить задание самостоятельно? провел ли он предварительное исследование перед тем, как скопипастить вопрос?" - это наиболее точно отражает процесс применения этой причины. Я бы дал более грубую оценку происходящему, но, пожалуй, [промолчу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct).

Закрытие не мешает пользователю дальше постить задания (минуса - хотя бы минимально, мешают!)

Хотите реально бороть "наглые" вопросы аля "сделайте за меня" - просто минусуйте их. [Этого более чем достаточно](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6201/177221).

Comment: А что тогда делать с вопросами по метке, где из активных людей сидит ну максимум пара человек вместе со мной? В итоге метка не только засоряется такими себе по качеству вопросами, но и потенциально мешает действительно интересным вопросам и ответам получить должное внимание.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, но закрытые вопросы тоже висят на сайте. В обоих случаях (закрытые и просто заминусованные) бот удалит с задержкой в несколько месяцев. Т. е. в свежих вопросах что-то такое болтаться будет, а в старых - нет.

Answer (score -8):

**Решать !!!**

*Ибо жизнь тяжела, а преподы жестоки :3*

---

"Вопрошающий всегда получает ответ " Камерунская пословица :3

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYfkZ.png

Answer (score -12):

Да закрывать их и дело с концом! Нечего сюсюкаться.

В качестве причины выбирайте "Другое" и своими словами описывайте причину для удаления, даже если они вам вполне понятны, но по вашему мнению должны быть закрыты.

Затем проголосовать против и также поступить с ответами на такие вопросы, дабы не поощрять отвечать на подобные вопросы в будущем. И по-хорошему стоит добавить сообщение с пояснением к соответствующим вопросам и ответам (в особенности к ответам, сам вопрос то будет закрыт с описывающей причиной, а вот голосование против ответа требует разъяснения), почему такие вопросы и ответы не желательно оставлять на данной площадке.

Comment: В случае SO - именно закрытие - это "сюсюкаться". Дергать 5 человек ради каждого домашнего задания.

Comment: _"проголосовать против и также поступить с ответами"_, можете немного раскрыть мысль? Предположим, что ответ верный и исчерпывающий. Почему стоит его минусовать?

Comment: @nomnoms12, уже обсуждалось отдельным вопросом, если не ошибаюсь и там пришли к выводу, что голосовать против ответов не надо.

Comment: @nomnoms12 знак не поощрять от сообщества.

Comment: Вот только минусы у корректного и полного ответа, без сопутствующих комментариев за что именно, будут давать ложную информацию новым участникам и тем кто просто пришел из гугла, да и по отношению к автору ответа отсутствие указания причины минуса выглядит скорее как хамство.

Comment: @rdorn стараюсь не скупиться на пояснение, но здравое уточнение.