# Добавить новый знак для задающих учебные вопросы

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, знаки

Есть предложение добавить новый знак, который бы выдавался за три закрытых вопроса по причине "Не по теме": "Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос."

Answer (score 7):

1. Не вижу смысла давать знак за отрицательное действие.
2. И от самой причины закрытия давно пора избавиться, но никак не выходит ((

Comment: Не является ответом. Не?

Comment: @edem, переформулировал.

Comment: Зачем избавляться? Отличная причина. Одна из моих любимых.

Comment: @edem, я [в соседнем вопрос расписал](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9634/178988).

Comment: @Qwertiy А вы бы не могли добавить вопрос-предложение на мете избавиться от данной причины закрытия? Я бы поддержал.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov можете сами предложить это, но я однозначно против.

Answer (score 5):

Данное слово несёт откровенно негативную эмоциональную составляющую, что будет способствовать конфликтам участников, вызывать отторжение, ссоры.

Подобному знаку не место в сети Stack Exchange. Возможно, вы не в курсе — у нас действуют [правила поведения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct), ваше предложение идёт вразрез с политикой ресурса.

Comment: Слово убрал, изменил название. В нём дело только или в целом в самом знаке?

Comment: @edem Сам вопрос домашки является разъединяющим сообщество уже который год. Тут хоть знак "Маладца, пять домашек решил" создавай -- слишком много недовольных будет, сама тема достаточно токсичная.

Comment: Есть не менее "отрицательный" знак, который даётся за удаление своего ответа под влиянием общества. И что? Не все же знаки надо получать, НО нужно отличать хорошее от плохого.

Comment: @edem Скажите, вы не в курсе, что на сайте не принято менять вопросы после того, как получены ответы? Вы отредактировали вопрос, обесценив смысл данных ответов.

Comment: С удовольствием верну, если оно не противоречит правилам, на ваш взгляд.

Comment: @edem, суть того знака - ты задал плохой вопрос, его заминусовали, ты это осознал и совершил хорошее действие - почистил за собой - и получил за это знак.

Comment: @Qwertiy кстати, хорошее предложение.