# Причина закрытия «учебные задания»: дубль два

Tags: обсуждение, причины-закрытия, домашки

Как вы уже должны были заметить, [причина закрытия «учебные задания» была возвращена](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10100/15479). Т.е, по сути, всё вернулось на круги своя. Теперь же можно попробовать зайти к проблеме домашек с другой стороны.

Для начала советую ознакомиться с обзором этой причины закрытия от участников:

- [Ответ от PashaPash](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9707/15479).
- [Старый ответ от jfs, ещё до ввода этой причины](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/233/15479).
- [Ответ от Qwertiy](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9710/15479).
- [Мой ответ с небольшой статистикой](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9711/15479).

Кратко:

- Простой вопрос - это не плохой вопрос. Даже "как сложить числа" - это вполне нормальный вопрос.
- SO - это база знаний. Если автор вопроса не сделал попыток решить проблему, это не означает, что вопрос вреден/не нужен базе знаний.
- Очень часто люди насильно к этой причине притягивают вопросы.

Проблемы:

- Причина слишком размыта, к ней притягивают за уши много вопросов.
- Закрывается много "простых" вопросов, хотя сами по себе такие вопросы могли бы быть полезны сообществу.

Из того, что предлагали:

- Переписать текст в этой причине закрытия.
- Добавить новые причины закрытия более специализированные. Например, для вопросов-картинок.

Я мог что-то упустить. Если у вас есть идеи/предложения, напишите в ответе ٩(◕‿◕｡)۶

Comment: *"Очень часто люди насильно к этой причине притягивают вопросы."* Можете привести примеры таких вопросов? Возможно в разных тегах ситуация разная, но в С/С++ я вроде ни разу такого не видел.

Comment: "дубль два" — двойной два.

Comment: @edem, https://slovar.cc/rus/ojegov/590080.html

Comment: Хотелось бы получить примеры закрытых атомарных вопросов, которые не являлись дубликатами

Comment: @Miron вот прям сейчас закроют https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1087198/15479.

Comment: **SO - это база знаний** Вы все еще в это верите? Реально SO - обычный форум по программированию, где 95% (условно) - ответы на вопросы, интересные только одному спрашивающему, и то в половине случаев только потому, что он слишком ленив, чтобы открыть книжку. Заметил, кстати, что сложные вопросы (где надо всерьез поработать, а не просто - вот 100кБ исходников, что-то (ни в коем случае не говоря что) не работает - исправьте) часто как раз остаются без ответа...

Comment: Скажите, вот сейчас натолкнулся на [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1088575/195342) - он не учебный, он не получит минусов. Все хорошо? Но **пользы** этот вопрос никому, кроме ТС, не принесет. Как быть с такими вопросами? "Лучше меньше, да лучше" или "дайте мне таблеток от жадности, да побольше, побольше!"? Интернет губит умение работать и думать, и даже искать информацию :( Умение искать свои ошибки ликвидировано как класс - спросил, ответили,Ю воткнул. Не получилось - опять возмущенно написал "не компилируется" без попытки подумать... Грустно!

Answer (score 10):

**Я считаю, эту причину менять не нужно.** "Работает - не трогай." (с)

> Причина слишком размыта, к ней притягивают за уши много вопросов.

Не видел ни одного незаслуженно закрытого ей вопроса.

Хотя, возможно, в разных тегах ситуация разная? Если кто-то сталкивался с таким, я был бы рад ссылкам на примеры.

> Простой вопрос - это не плохой вопрос. Даже "как сложить числа" - это вполне нормальный вопрос.

*"Как сложить два числа в языке Х"* и так не попадает под эту причину закрытия, потому что это не "учебное задание".

А вот *"напишите программу на языке Х, которая принимает два целых числа, складывает их, и выводит результат"* - попадает, и вполне заслуженно.

> SO - это база знаний. Если автор вопроса не сделал попыток решить проблему, это не означает, что вопрос вреден/не нужен базе знаний.

Эта причина **не** запрещает все вопросы без попытки решения. Она запрещает только **учебные задания** без попытки решения.

Если вопрос — это просто копипаст (или пересказ) условия задачи по программированию — он нам действительно не нужен.

Comment: Квертий ещё в прошлых обсуждениях ссылки приводил.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Можно ссылку на пост со ссылками? Я его когда в прошлый раз спрашивал, он тоже сказал искать в предыдущих обсуждениях. Я ничего такого не нашел. Наоборот, нашел [пост](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9632/215103) PashaPash, где он пишет, что *"Сейчас ей вроде бы не злоупотребляют"*.

Comment: Известно же, что не работает.

Comment: @Qwertiy Кому известно? Мне - неизвестно. Если этой причиной дествительно злоупотербляют "очень часто", как написано в вопросе, то найти примеры должно быть несложно.

Comment: Не только по метке С++ все закрывают справедливо, но и например по метке [python]. Абсолютно согласен с вашим ответом, лучше и не скажешь!

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ну вот сейчас закроют скоро https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1087198/15479.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Добавил свой голос за закрытие. Имхо, справедливо закрыли. Домашка? Скорее всего да. Попытка решения есть? Нет.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat о том и речь. Закрываются нормальные вопросы. И проблема в том, что те, кто их закрывает, думает, что делают всё правильно.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica А он нормальный? Мне такие вопросы не нравятся. Да и там 6 минусов; вангую, если не этой причиной, то какой-нибудь другой бы закрыли. (Помните, когда причину отключали, количество закрытых вопросов не поменялось.)

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica в целом как таковой вопрос неплох, но в текущем виде для базы знаний все равно бесполезен. Нужно из него вычищать весь шум и переписывать не несущий смысла заголовок. И даже после этого вопрос прибьется как дубликат.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Да правильно его закрыли. Ну какая к чертям собачьим польза от вопроса, для решения которого надо тупо заглянуть в справку и найти подходящий метод? кому нужна в Инете ещё одна копия "избранное из мануала"? Вот кабы человеку надо было подменять ввод на лету непосредственно в процессе ввода - да и то, не силён я в питонах, может, там есть где-то и способы посимвольного ввода, к коим можно прикрутить трансляцию... вот только офигеть как вряд ли ТСу нужно именно это.

Comment: @Akina ну...SO позиционируется как "база ответов на **все** вопрос" ^_^"

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Можно, я поставлю акцент на последнее слово -  "база ответов на все **вопросы**"? Спасибо... Вы правда полагаете, что ту тему по ссылке вообще можно квалифицировать как вопрос? у меня лично по сему поводу ну очень большие сомнения... это скорее выступление в стиле "сами мы не местные, помогите кто чем может". Кстати, самый раздражающий тип постингов, и преимущественно из-за таких и должна, просто обязана, существовать обсуждаемая причина закрытия.

Comment: @Akina но его можно подправить. Я смотрю на это так, что раз люди постоянно подобное спрашивают, то, вероятно, кто-то и в будущем придёт с таким же вопросом. Конкретно этот вопрос в текущем виде, да, бесполезен, в целом.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1089816/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy Не считается, он пока не закрыт. :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, 2 голоса уже есть. Даже если не закроют, то его наличие в очереди проверок отвлекает 5 человек.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1089402/178988

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1093403/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy Не закрыт, не считается. Там один голос за закрытие. Вы его отредактировали и привели в приличный вид (до редактирования вопрос был плохой, и если голос оставили до редактирования, я с ним согласен).

Comment: Предыдущий вопрос мне не нравится, еще тогда проголосовал за закрытие.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, если можно отредактировать, то надо брать и редактировать, а не голосовать за закрытие.

Comment: @Qwertiy ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Мне кажется, тут каждый сам решает. Заставить всех редактировать не получится.

Answer (score 9):

В целом я согласен с [ответом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/10148/176217) @HolyBlackCat, но добавлю пару своих копеек. Наличие готовой причины закрытия нужно, т.к. это позволяет не писать каждый раз коммент для кастомной причины и при этом быть (может и не всегда на все 100%) уверенным, что вопрос закрывается с подходящей формулировкой и не требующей торга с совестью (типа закрыл по причине, которой было проще воспользоваться, но она фактически не подходит к ситуации).

Текущая формулировка намного лучше, чем односложный коммент вида "делай домашку сам" в нестандартной причине закрытия. Вероятно, её можно сделать лучше, но, как известно, "лучшее - враг хорошего". Попытки написать её каким-то максимально юридически корректными словами могут привести к тому, что эту причину просто перестанут понимать (достаточно взглянуть на вариант со словом "атомарный" в соседнем ответе).

Стоит задаться вопросом - чего мы хотим добиться переформулировкой вопроса? Если речь о том, чтобы уменьшить кол-во некорректно закрытых вопросов, то давайте тогда собирать список таких вопросов. На примерах можно будет попробовать сформулировать (скорректировать) причину закрытия. Но стоит понимать, что если вопрос был закрыт как "домашка", т.е. его присутствие на сайте не понравилось участникам, то изменение формулировки ничего не изменит, т.к. формулировка не меняет самих вопросов, которые закрываются. Как бы не написать причину, она по-прежнему останется "домашкой" в сухом остатке. А домашкам тут не (очень) рады.

Для несогласных с закрытием всегда есть механизм переоткрытия. Но можно пойти и другим путём. Если кажется, что вопрос был закрыт незаслуженно и его можно было бы переформулировать и сделать полезным сообществу, можно просто написать свой MCVE и в идеале даже дать на него ответ. Таким образом не придётся тратить время и нервы на попытку переоткрытия (которая может и не удаться), и не находиться в сомнениях по поводу того, насколько можно изменить суть и тело чужого вопроса. Свой открытый вопрос с заимствованной (извлечённой) идеей проще привести к подходящему для сообществу виду, чем чужой и закрытый.

Comment: "Для несогласных с закрытием всегда есть механизм переоткрытия" Так там в очередях эти же закрывашки сидят)

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica "нужно запретить голосовать всем, кто не согласен с моей точкой зрения"

Comment: Запрещаю запрещать!

Answer (score 0):

> Вопрос объединяет несколько атомарных независимых действий, например, математику и ввод-вывод. Возможно его стоит разбить на соответствующие атомарные вопросы, но предварительно стоит убедиться, что такие вопросы ещё не задавались, потому что в большинстве случаев вероятность существования таких вопросов достаточно велика.

Тут я хотел отразить что:

- атомарные вопросы - это хорошие вопросы
- участник может и должен скомпоновать программу сам
- должно быть понятно, что надо задачу сначала поделить, потом поискать на сайте, а затем уже, если не вышло, делить вопрос на части
- явно не удалось отразить, что сам вопрос можно превратить в одну из частей, а не забрасывать

PS: Взято из [этого ответа (+15 -1)](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9710/178988), сформулировано на основе [этого обсуждения (+26 -3)](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9634/178988).

Comment: Идея интересная, но я считаю, что нужна более простая формулировка. Те, кто приходят сюда с домашкой, вряд ли знают слово "атомарный".

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, ну предлагай свою. Главное чтоб закрывающие знали :)

Comment: Использование слова "атомарный" в значении "неделимый" — это как Землю называть плоской. ПС. Про латинщину вообще молчу.

Comment: @edem átomos (от которого "атомарный" и образовано) с **греческого** - неделимая сущность.

Comment: @edem, ну так предлагай свой вариант в ответах.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica речь не про "атомос", а про "atom", так что латинщина. Ну и в "неделимости" вопроса на RUso, я не был бы так уверен.

Comment: Вообще это тавтология какая-то. По-моему "атомарный" и "одно независимое действие" - это одно и то же

Comment: @Miron, имеется в виду: 1. Если вопрос атомарный (как извлечь квадратный корень?), то он разрешён. 2. Если вопрос объединяет несколько действий, но они не являются независимыми (при использовании колонок внутри inline-блока он оказывается неправильной ширина), то он разрешён. 3. Если вопрос объединяет несколько атомарных независимых действий (как считать число и извлечь из него квадратный корень?), то его надо делить.

Comment: Этот вопрос - об атомарности вопросов - *imho* - никак не коррелирует с рассматриваемой темой учебных вопросов.

Answer (score 0):

1. Не простой, а атомарный. "Напишите консольные крестики-нолики" - простая задача, значит она неплоха? Нет, она плоха, так как она не атомарна.
2. Хотелось бы получить примеры закрытых атомарных вопросов, не являющихся дубликатами. Желательно в количестве хотя бы 5 штук.

Действительно, думаю, что выражение "учебное задание" не очень точно. Но, по крайней мере, закрытия атомарных(не являющихся дубликатами) вопросов не происходит потому, что если вопрос является атомарным и лишен лишней конкретики, то распознать его как учебное задание наверняка можно только по косвенным признакам.
Но есть же и те вопросы, которые не являются атомарными, но которые все же стоит оставить? Думаю, есть два таких типа вопросов:

1. Kогда затраты на разделение слишком велики
2. Kогда вопрос в неразделенном виде более полезен для базы знаний.

Думаю, стоит заменить эту причину на что-то типа этого:

> Вопрос не является атомарным, - то есть его можно разделить на несколько разных вопросов. Вопрос может быть неатомарным, если затраты на его разделение слишком велики или он в таком виде более полезен для базы знаний

Comment: "Атомарный" - слишком абстрактный термин. Если автор вопроса не по правилам задаёт вопрос, то вряд ли он поймёт, что означает "атомарный".

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica вот же пояснение(значение слова неатомарный) - "<...> то есть его можно разделить на несколько разных вопросов."

Comment: Я больше к тому, чтобы в описании причины закрытия использовать термины, которые не нужно пояснять)

Comment: Не, с такой формулировкой можно будет абсолютно любой вопрос закрыть.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica "дубликат... Вопрос уже задавался ранее, и на него уже есть ответ." - а это что :D

Comment: Штошь ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Qwertiy А есть вопросы, которые не являются атомарными и которые подлежат разделению? Неатомарный вопрос по определению можно разделить, - что, кстати, я отразил к пояснению выражения "не является атомарным"

Comment: @Miron, 90% вопросов не атомарны.

Comment: @Qwertiy чем они более неатомарны, тем они менее полезны для базы знаний, так(за исключением некоторых часто встречающихся задач, которые хочется просто скопипастить)? В идеале все вопросы должны быть атомарны. Думаю, проблема в превращении задачи в атомарную бывает слишком сложна  в решении. Думаю, это стоит прописать в формулировке причины. Например, так: "задача может быть неатомарной, если затраты на разделение задачи слишком велики".

Comment: Вообще же стоит определиться с тем, чем является этот сайт - базой знаний или сайтом помощи. От ответа напрямую зависит формулировка причины закрытия.

Comment: @Qwertiy 90% вопросов на сайте — мусор ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @andreymal (｡•́︿•̀｡)

Comment: Зачастую проблемы атомарные, но не всегда в неработающем коде их легко выявить

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы закрыть эту тему окончательно, я предлагаю проголосовать еще раз. Ответы за которые надо будет голосовать предлагаю сделать такие:

- Оставить причину учебные задания в оригинальной форме:

  > **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос**. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности** при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.
- Не закрывать домашки вообще.
- Вариант Квертия:

  > Вопрос объединяет несколько атомарных независимых действий, например, математику и ввод-вывод. Возможно его стоит разбить на соответствующие атомарные вопросы, но предварительно стоит убедиться, что такие вопросы ещё не задавались, потому что в большинстве случаев вероятность существования таких вопросов достаточно велика.
- Ввести метку.
- Закрывать домашки по другой причине, как предложил Harry:

  > Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, опечаткой или незнанием азов.

Comment: Будем голосовать пока не получим нужный расклад голосов? Позиция большинства давно понятна.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev Позиция может и понятна, но некоторые считают, что я голосование испортил. Я думаю стоит голосовать еще раз, тогда уж точно все будет ясно.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica Имхо, этот тред можно считать голосованием.