# Как-то не так работает блок "Важное на Мете"

Tags: дефект, блок-важных-вопросов

Вопрос "[Причина закрытия «учебные задания»: дубль два](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10141/178988)" почему-то показывается в обсуждаемом, а не в важном, хотя соответствующая метка на нём есть. А вот с "[Возвращение причины закрытия вопросов «учебные задания»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10100/178988)" метку уже сняли, а он всё ещё в важном. Оба действия 7 часов назад.

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Жди сутки. Оно может надолго кешироваться. Хотя, есть вероятность, что старый баг всплыл. Завтра посмотрим)

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica, но вопрос же в обсуждаемом. Разве они не вместе считаются?

Comment: Да фиг знает, как оно там считается. С "Важным" всегда странности. Я обычно сутки жду, а потом уже иду на MSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем-то, если посмотреть [сообщения по теме](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342549/260198), то сотрудники [рекомендуют ждать сутки](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342538/how-or-when-is-the-featured-tag-supposed-to-take-effect#comment1146889_342538).

Вероятно, кешируется на 24 часа.