# Надо ли допускать выполнение за других их домашних заданий на SO?

Tags: обсуждение

Я на SO полтора месяца активно, часто вижу вопросы из серии "сделайте мне "домашку" (без какой-либо попытки сделать самому).
При этом на SO есть правило: "Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос."
Но я периодически вижу, что эти задания выполняются участниками SO (для поднятия репутации? для подрыва системы образования?:-))
Когда же я поставил  на пару таких выполнений (сделанных другими поверх моей рекомендации автору самому сделать "домашку" и моего пояснения, что надо прочитать, чтобы справиться) тревоги модератору с пояснением, почему тревога поставлена, то тревоги эти отклонили с сообщением: "тревоги стоит использовать, только чтобы предупредить модераторов о необходимости их вмешательства".

**1) Почему, если такие учебные задания недопустимы по правилам форума, то ответы на них допустимы?
2) Почему вопросы все такие не закрывают сразу, если задания недопустимы? Я на них тревог много ставил - мало что закрыли.**

Возможно, я неверно понимаю правила и зря трачу время на улучшение качества вопросов на форуме?

Comment: 1) автоматически определить домашку, средствами бота -  нельзя. Надо ждать людей. Пока люди закроют - кто-то ответ напишет. 2) в принципе по той же причине, что в 1.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, с ботом - конечно так. Я о том, что почему не удалять такие вопросы, раз уж тревога пришла, да и ответы вместе с вопросами? Неудаление их фактически поощряет их размещение.

Comment: А зачем удалять? А если вопрос решат исправить, чтобы он дотягивал до требований? А он пшик - и растворился))

Comment: На самом деле проблем на ресурсе целый ворох и ты ничего не сможешь с этим сделать)) смирись)) Всё что ты можешь: если считаешь, что в вопросе/ответе проблемы - поставить минус, если считаешь нужным и комментарий (тоже, если считаешь, что стОит) и пойти дальше ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ясно, спасибо. Забью тогда. Но вера в людей (что вопрос "сделайте мне домашку" преобразится в "вот, я всё сделал!" на коротком интервале) мне не близка.

Comment: Конечно, школьникам/студентам-халявщикам делать что ли больше нечего, как доводить вопрос до ума))) Они раскопировали вопрос по ресурсам и пошли пиво пить. Пришли - посмотрели ответы, кто им написал  - тот молодец браток, кто нет - паразиты :)))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, да. В моём личном топе вопросы без попыток решить с комментарием: "Вот олимпиадная задача, решение нужно срочно", "Я устраиваюсь на работу, дали тестовую задачу", "Я взял задание" (ясно, что на фрилансе).

Comment: с одной стороны забавно, с другой даже как-то странно что на такие вопросы отвечают модераторы, вместо того, чтобы их удалить (причем жалоба была подана) - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1403741/483580

Comment: @Pekor, да, прикольно....

Comment: @Pekor правилами не запрещено отвечать на такие вопросы, и нет правила, которое бы утверждало, что такие вопросы нужно удалять. Закрывать - допустим, есть соответствующая причина закрытия, но не удалять. С закрытием само сообщество должно справиться, модератор для этого не нужен. В принципе вопрос будет удален через какое-то время автоматически, т.к. он сильно заминусованный.

Comment: @insolor, как-то странно. Если "Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос", то как правила могут разрешать отвечать на недопустимый (!) вопрос? Результат анализа слова "допустимый" подразумевает необходимость не допускать при невыполнении условий. А ответы ещё и поощряют размещение подобного.

Comment: @Сергей была большая дискуссия по поводу данной причины закрытия, к консенсусу не пришли. Поэтому "недопустимость" учебных вопросов в данном случае лучше воспринимать как рекомендацию, а не как запрет. По поводу ответов - просто наличие любой причины закрытия само по себе не запрещает давать ответы (пока вопрос не закрыт фактически). В целом, придирки к ответам не "недопустимые" вопросы я бы отнес к "вахтерству", а не к полезной деятельности

Comment: @insolor, ясно, спасибо. Этически здесь вопрос в том, зачем SO нужен - для поднятия среднего уровня программистов или для любой "помощи" (вопрос, помощь ли это в конечном итоге для получающего ответ), тем самым этот уровень потенциально снижая. Можно попытки борьбы с этим звать и "вахтерством". Но, как я написал выше, далее на подобные случаи я внимания не обращаю.

Comment: @Сергей для помощи программистам И создания базы знаний. Одно другого не исключает. Часть ответов никогда больше никому не понадобится, часть поможет очень многим. Цели повышения уровня программистов вообще не стоИт, для этого есть учебные заведения, курсы, и т.д.

Comment: @insolor А тут не консенсус? [Причина закрытия «учебные задания»: дубль два](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10141/215103).

Comment: @Сергей На английском SO к правилам относятся строже, но даже там ответы не удаляют только за то, что вопрос офф-топик. На русском SO тем более, здесь все более сумбурно и людей меньше. Если видите такой ответ и хотите что-то сделать - лепите минус и объясняете отвечающему, что на офф-топик вопросы не надо отвечать (["Отвечайте на хорошо заданные вопросы"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) и т. п.).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, ясно, спасибо, но сберегу своё время.  Что толку отвечать таким образом , если после этого поверх идут два ответа с решениями, а модераторы пишут, что это не повод для тревоги:-)
могу только сказать, что правила, где говорится о "недопустимости" чего-то, что на практике вполне допустимо, не вызывают у меня большого уважения, так как только сбивают с толку. Так бы и писали - "нежелательно".

Comment: @Сергей Весь русский SO "не вызывает большого уважения". ;_; Может английский вам понравится больше.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, может и понравится больше, но живу-то я в РФ. И в текущих условиях разумно развивать базу знаний для своих сограждан (90% из которых пишут на ужасающем по уровню английском, когда решают задать вопрос на SO:-). Ну и владеющих русским граждан соседних стран, конечно, если они этот сегмент SO предпочитают.

Comment: @Сергей *"в текущих условиях"* Английский SO - база знаний для всех, и для русских тоже. Все равно без минимального знания английского нормально программировать невозможно.